# rsync fails with multiple SRC

Tags: osx, rsync

I am logged into a Mac (running OSX 10.12) over ssh and have entered the following commends.

```
REMOTE=Milliways.local:/Users/ian
rsync -a --delete-during $REMOTE/bin ~/
rsync -a --delete-during $REMOTE/Documents ~/
```

This works OK, and updates the appropriate directories.

I tried to include both directories in a single rsync using:-

```
rsync -a --delete-during $REMOTE/bin  $REMOTE/Documents ~/
```

This produces an error message (basically what I would get from rsync -h)

```
~$ rsync -a --delete-during $REMOTE/bin  $REMOTE/Documents ~/
rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29
Copyright (C) 1996-2006 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
<http://rsync.samba.org/>
Capabilities: 64-bit files, socketpairs, hard links, symlinks, batchfiles,
              inplace, IPv6, 64-bit system inums, 64-bit internal inums
…
```

I have studied the man files, which seem to support what I am trying, specifically

```
Usage: rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... DEST
```

While for these Directories there is no real reason I need to combine, for others I need to use a single SRC to maintain hardlinks.

Can anyone suggest what is wrong?

> As suggested in muru's answer I installed brew.

Comment: The first line of the error might offer a hint. As it is, I am unable to reproduce. Works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Truck.app is an rsync client for Mac that comes with rsync 3.1.3 and will let you just drag and drop to do simple operations like this.  http://bonhardcomputing.com/truck/  (disclaimer: I am a developer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macOS version of `rsync` doesn't support multiple remote sources. Contrast the lines for remote sources in the macOS manpage:

```
rsync [OPTION]... [USER@]HOST:SRC [DEST]
rsync [OPTION]... [USER@]HOST::SRC [DEST]
```

With those for local sources:

```
rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... DEST
rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... [USER@]HOST:DEST
rsync [OPTION]... SRC [SRC]... [USER@]HOST::DEST
```

And with those in [the Ubuntu manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/rsync.html) for remote sources:

```
Access via remote shell:
 Pull: rsync [OPTION...] [USER@]HOST:SRC... [DEST]
 Push: rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [USER@]HOST:DEST
```

The lack of ellipsis in the first set indicates that multiple remote source locations aren't supported by the macOS version of `rsync`.

On Ubuntu 16.04:

```
~ rsync --version
rsync  version 3.1.2  protocol version 31
Copyright (C) 1996-2015 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
```

macOS `rsync` is an antique. Update with homebrew or similar:

```
~ brew info rsync
rsync: stable 3.1.3 (bottled)
Utility that provides fast incremental file transfer
https://rsync.samba.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/rsync/3.1.3_1 (9 files, 756.1KB) *
  Poured from bottle on 2018-06-11 at 12:38:53
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/rsync.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: autoconf ✔
```

Comment: This seems to be the case (although I don't entirely understand the man AND the error could be clearer!) For those cases where it is essential I I will initiate from the other end, although this makes the cases where sudo is needed difficult.

Comment: I have never been comfortable with brew, and as this is not my Mac, I am reluctant to modify system software.

Comment: Brew installs to `/usr/local/bin`. The system `rsync` remains untouched in `/usr/bin` if you ever need it.

Comment: OK, I installed brew on my own Mac, then `brew install rsync` - now how do I run it? rsync --version still shows 2.6.9

Comment: @Milliways probably this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/281116/205028